# excel 2016 VBA macro to clear cell ranges, then insert data in blank cells

Tags: excel, vba

The purpose of my macro is to reset my sheet.

My macro first does the clearcontents fundtion within several different cell ranges.

Next I want to fill some of those cells back with 0

I found one recommendation which I changed their = "ON" to = "0"

> Intersect(Selection, Range("D7:R23")) = "0"

I get the following,

> Run-time error '91'
>
> Object variable or With block variable not set

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Code is as follows:

```
Sub Clearcells()

Range("D2:Z2").ClearContents

Range("D3:AG3").ClearContents

Range("D4:AG4").ClearContents

Range("AE2:AG2").ClearContents

Range("C7:R23").ClearContents

Range("W7:Y23").ClearContents

Range("AC7:AF23").ClearContents

Range("B27:AG43").ClearContents

Intersect(Selection, Range("D7:R23")) = "0"

Intersect(Selection, Range("W7:Y23")) = "0"

Intersect(Selection, Range("AC7:AF23")) = "0"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide your full code so we can try and help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that no `Select`'ed cells fall in the **D7:R23** range.  The two ranges are completely disjoint.  For example:

[image]

In the above example, I `Select`'ed the block **A1:B5** before I ran the line of code.

Comment: Does this mean I have to go Row by Row?

Comment: @Miam  **NO** It means that when this line of code is executed, the `Select`'ed cells must overlap the **D7:R27** block of cells

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this programming macro's. So, I have to select the cells before running the macro?

Comment: @Miam  The single line of code you posted assumes you *(or the previous lines of code)* have `Select`'ed some or all the cells in the block.

Answer (score 1):

Try this; Your trying to do a simple clear the then write into the empty cells; you don't need to use Intersect and you can combine all the ranges to shorten your code.

```
Range("D2:Z2, D3:AG3, D4:AG4, AE2:AG2, C7:R23, W7:Y23, AC7:AF23, B27:AG43").ClearContents
Range("D7:R23, W7:Y23, AC7:AF23") = "0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to clear, then insert, so this code simply replaces all of the cells with a 0 value. Which is ultimately what I wanted to do.

```
Sub Clearcells()    
Range("D2:Z2").ClearContents    
Range("D3:AG3").ClearContents    
Range("D4:AG4").ClearContents    
Range("AE2:AG2").ClearContents    
Range("B27:AG43").ClearContents    
Range("C7:C23").ClearContents    
Range("D7:R23") = "0"    
Range("W7:Y23") = "0"    
Range("AC7:AF23") = "0"    
End Sub
```